# What maps to a plane in a stereographic projection of a 3-sphere to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: geometry, stereographic-projections

Any straight line in a stereographic projecton from a 2-sphere to $\mathbb{R}^2$ maps back to a circle passing through the projection point. That I can see why: the rays between the projection point and the straight line defines a half-plane that intersects with the 2-sphere and passes through the projection point. Since the intersection between a sphere and a plane is a circle, a circle it is.

What about a plane in a stereographic projecton from a 3-sphere to $\mathbb{R}^3$ ?

I assume it maps back to a 2-sphere passing through the point of projection in the 3-sphere, but I am just extrapolating from the lower dimension case.

EDIT:
Backgroung: in [my game](https://github.com/lvella/glome), I use a stereographic projection to map the surface of a 3-sphere (the game world, where points are represented by 4-D unit vectors), into a "ordinary" 3-D flat space, in order to be rendered. I want to know what the far clipping plane in my view frustum maps back into 4-D coordinates. I hope it is a sphere. Is it?

Comment: Isn't stereographic projection a mapping from a $n$ sphere (minus a point) to $\mathbb{R}^n$? How is it a map $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @KeeferRowan Sorry, I fixed it. I said $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ because I am using euclidean coordinates to define the points on the n-sphere, in the software I am writing.

Comment: @CloudJR Yes, I understand.

Comment: Not sure what you would exactly like as an answer. If you are seeking for some geometry - visualisation argument, I can't help you in higher dimension. There are some visualisations on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Stereographic_projection as well as formal definition, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @prosinac I am satisfied with an answer like: "it is a 2-sphere embedded in the 3-sphere", or whatever it is the right answer.

Comment: Ok sorry, now I see what you mean. I'm pretty confident that you are right, because of the same reasoning you posted in $2$-sphere case. (Rays connecting plane and projection point form a $3$D subspace, and intersection of $3$D subspace and $3$-sphere is a $2$-sphere). I tried algebraic proof but didn't manage it even in $2$-sphere case. Essentially, you would need to prove that inverse of line/plane lies in plane/$3$D subspace. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Generalizations. Let me know if you need algebraic proof and I might try doing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a 2-sphere embedded in the 3-sphere.

Reasoning as you did in the lower-dimensional case, you could say that the set of rays from the projection point in the 3-sphere to the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ form a half-hyperplane intersecting the 3-sphere at the projection point. The intersection between the 3-sphere and a hyperplane is a 2-sphere.

But let's check that using coordinates. Stereographic projection of the sphere $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1$ from $(0,0,0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ has the coordinate expression
\begin{equation}
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \mapsto \left( \frac{x_1}{1-x_4} , \frac{x_2}{1-x_4} , \frac{x_3}{1-x_4} \right)
\end{equation}
A point $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ in the 3-sphere maps to the plane
\begin{equation}
Ay_1 + By_2 + Cy_3 + D = 0
\end{equation}
in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if
\begin{equation}
Ax_1+Bx_2+Cx_3-Dx_4 + D=0
\end{equation}
This is the equation of a hyperplane through $(0,0,0,1)$.

That a hyperplane does in fact intersect a 3-sphere in a 2-sphere can be verified either synthetically or analytically, using the lower-dimensional case as a guide.